# Rounding in Python.

Tags: python

How would I round 'com' in this Python code?

```
def percentage(com,rd):
    apl = [10,10,10,5,5,20,10,10,10,10]
    if age > 15:
        t=sum(apl)
    if age < 15:
        t=sum(apl) + 10
    com=rd/t*100
    *round(com,0)*
    return com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty fine, except that you have to store the returned value somewhere:

```
def percentage(rd):
    apl = [10,10,10,5,5,20,10,10,10,10]
    if age > 15:
        t=sum(apl)
    if age < 15:
        t=sum(apl) + 10
    com=rd/t*100 #this overwrites whatever the passed argument com was.
    com = round(com,0) #assign the rounded value back to com
    return com
```

Also, you don't actually need com as a parameter, since you assigned it in the function.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
com = round(com,0)
```

`round` is a function that just returns a value, does not modify the variable you provide it. You have to assign that value yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the `round` function. Say you wanted to round it to the nearest ten:

```
>>> i = 222
>>> print round(i, -1)
220.0
```

Comment: He's already using the `round` function in the question.